# owncloud user creation from remote script and login

Tags: php, authentication, owncloud

I'm trying to create a php script to create an account with owncloud 6. So far I've done this:

```
//create user with OC_User class. The user gets created in table ownc_users
$creation_check = OC_User::createUser( $parametri["uid"], $parametri["password"] );

//I'll then do a login
OC_User::login( $parametri["uid"], $parametri["password"] );

$logged_user_username = OC_User::getUser(); 


//check if login went ok
if(!empty($logged_user_username)){

//Then I create the folders copyng them from the skeleton
\OC\Files\Filesystem::initMounts();
\OC\Files\Filesystem::initMountPoints( $parametri["uid"] );
}
```

Everything works fine, However until I do a login from the webpage of owncloud, the tables ownc_filecache and ownc_storages are not populated. This is a problem to me because I need them later in other scripts. For instance if I pass to the scripts the following values:

```
$parametri["uid"] = "test"
$parametri["password"] = "test"
```

- The user is created (ownc_user table is populated).
- All the folders are also created (from skeleton...I can see them
  in the user data folder).
- Table ownc_storages is not populated with data (storage id is not
  associated to the user).
- Table ownc_filecache is not populated

If I'll do a login from the owncloud webpage (opening it from browser), I can see that after the login ownc_storages and ownc_filecache are populated with data.

What am I missing to complete the full creation of an account in owncloud? Why these two tables are not initialized?